# Hide dropdown options based on selected radio button and also on page onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-arrays

I have a form with radio buttons and a dropdown list.

If the user selects 'girls', I only want to display caroms and chess, as specified in the `girlsGames` variable.

If the user selects boys, I want to show the dropdown options for a `boysGames` variable.

Here is my code:

```
<form action="">
    <label for="boys"><input type="radio" id="boys" name="gender" value="boys">Boys</label>
    <label for="girls"><input type="radio" id="girls" name="gender" value="girls">Girls</label>
    <select name="games" id="">
    <option value="">select games</option>
    <option value="caroms">Caroms</option>
    <option value="chess">Chess</option>
    <option value="football">Football</option>
    <option value="rugby">Rugby</option>
    </select>
  </form>
    <script>
    var girlsGames = ['caroms', 'chess'];
            $('input:radio').change(function(event) {

          });
    </script>
```

Comment: @Pete, It's only just example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is one of many approaches, based on adding classes to specific options and hiding / showing all options:

```js
var girlsGames = ['caroms', 'chess'];
            $('input:radio').change(function(event) {
             
              if(event.target.value == 'girls') {
                 $('option').hide();
                 $('.girls').show();
              } else if (event.target.value == 'boys'){
                 $('option').show();
              }
              
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
    <label for="boys"><input type="radio" id="boys" name="gender" value="boys">Boys</label>
    <label for="girls"><input type="radio" id="girls" name="gender" value="girls">Girls</label>
    <select name="games" id="">
    <option value="" class="girls">select games</option>
    <option value="caroms" class="girls">Caroms</option>
    <option value="chess" class="girls">Chess</option>
    <option value="football">Football</option>
    <option value="rugby">Rugby</option>
    </select>
  </form>
```

Comment: thanks @Marcin, can you add trigger also if girls are selected onload page